# Connect to Wampserver Database

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I'm using JSP and I want to connect to a local mySQL database thorough my Java files.

I have this :

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection((database_path),"admin","admin");

What should the path be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are well explained in [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/connect-jsp-mysql.shtml).

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usermaster"; 
...
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
```

Comment: Since links often break, it is good to post a small snippet of the relevant code as well :)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to stackoverflow, btw :)